# mouse keeps loading after opening visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-10, loading

Whenever I open visual studio code my mouse keeps loading endlessly.
But the moment I close VS Code it just stops.
I'm not sure if it's because of some extension I installed or something else.

[image: mouse loading]

Comment: Is VS Code usable? If so, you can run the `Developer: Reload with extensions disabled` command to check whether it is caused by an extension.

Comment: How do I run this command? I can't run it in VScode nor in the console. I did manage to disable all the extensions through the GUI. And the problem is solved but is there a way to pinpoint the exact extension or should I try them out one by one?

Comment: Commands are run from the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette), which is brought up using `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`P`. And yes, enabling them one after another is the only way to determine which extension causes the problem.